# Two point conversion from 15 yard line?

Tags: rules, american-football

During preseason, the NFL are [trialling](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap2000000343912/article/nfl-will-test-pats-from-the-15yard-line-not-the-20) having extra points snapped from the 15 yard line. During the [Giants-Bills](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap2000000373754/article/six-things-you-need-to-know-from-giantsbills-opener) preseason opener, all three extra points were successfully kicked.

But what would happen if a team tried to go for two points. Can they call a fake, and try to score from 15 yards out? If they reach the endzone, it still worth 2 points? Or can they declare their intentions, and go for the endzone from the 2 yard line? Or if they are desperate (last seconds of match, two points down), would they have to call a regular play from 15 yards out to score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from the [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/sports/wp/2014/08/03/nfls-preseason-experiment-with-longer-extra-point-begins-sunday-night/)

> In the NFL’s preseason experiment, the ball will be placed at the **15**-yard line, making for a 33-yard extra point. **Two-point conversion attempts will continue to come from the 2-yard line**.

Other articles referencing 15 yards: <sub>[[1]](http://espn.go.com/blog/baltimore-ravens/post/_/id/11752/justin-tucker-opposes-longer-extra-points), [[2]](http://nesn.com/2014/08/tablets-longer-extra-points-highlight-new-changes-in-hall-of-fame-game/), [[3]](http://www.newsday.com/sports/football/giants/extra-points-get-extra-long-for-giants-bills-game-1.8951005)</sub>

But the main point: **Yes, if this were to actually be implemented, 2 point conversions would remain the same**.

As far as faking from the extra point spot, as @Duncan says, as far as the rule states at the moment, nothing else changes really besides the yard you hike the ball from for an extra point. So of course, if you were going to go for 2, you'd make it clear and hike from the 2 rather than trying to trick them and starting 13 yards further back.

<sub>I do see 20 yard extra point hikes referenced in a few articles, but generally it's 15 yards. Since this is just an experiment, I'm sure the NFL was rumoring several different distances they might consider.</sub>

Comment: You are right about the 15 yards rather than 20. I changed my link in the question to a newer one from the NFL noting the change.

Comment: 15 and 20 were both being thrown around, but it seems like 15 is what they would actually go with if this were to actually be implemented.

Comment: With regard to the other portion of your question, I don't see any reason why the team couldn't fake an extra point and go for 2. I think it would be an incredibly low value play, but they should be able to do it.

Comment: @Duncan, agreed, thanks for mentioning that I, kind of failed to mention that part. Since this is still an experiment by the NFL, I think it's safe to say all other rules related to extra points would be inherited as they are currently, unless otherwise noted.

Comment: I do wonder about making the rule more like rugby. You kick the extra point from as far back as you like, but it has to be hiked from a point straight back from where the touchdown was actually scored. It would probably make 2 point conversions a more appealing options for touchdowns scored in the corner.

Comment: Can you add the part about the fake to your answer? Like Duncan says it would be a very unlikely play to call. I guess it is more likely that after a fumbled snap the holder would try to improvise a play to get 2 points.

Comment: @Fillet: I saw a game on TV once where the score was tied 11-11 just before halftime because the first point-after snap was fumbled and recovered.